# Ionic 3 - Enable Tabs on different page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I use Tabs component in my App.

If i go from **SideMenu** to **any page** (not in Tabs), component Tabs not visible.

How i can show Tabs on any page?

My code in **app.components.ts**:

```
this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push('MyProjectsPage');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic you normally have a tab-page as a wrapper around your normal pages. So if you open one of the tabs the tab-page will be displayed and load the *normal* page inside it.

In your **app.html** you would write:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="projectsPage"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And in your **app.component.ts** you would write:

```
projectsPage = MyProjectsPage;
```

See the [Ionic API Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/).